# Open application after NFC read

Tags: android, nfc, applinks

I have an Android application. It opens with deep links like `myapp://params`.

I have QR tags with an address like `http://myaddress.com/myapp/params` that loads a page with the following content:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>MyApp</title>
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url = myapp://params">
    </head>
</html>
```

When I read these tags in a QR reader, it shows me the address and when I click ok the `http-equiv="refresh"` does the rest and opens up the application with the passed params.

If I read the same address `http://myaddress.com/myapp/params` from a NFC tag by simply laying the phone on it, it stops on the browser page and does not open the application.

Why is that? Are there special Android restrictions?

Comment: I have the same issue. from what I have read browser won't automatically redirect you unless the user performed an action on the webpage (such as clicking the button)

Comment: So i could add a button with a bit of JS ?